# unable to cat files from crontab - cat: 0652-050 - unix AIX

Tags: cron, sendmail, aix

I am trying to send email using the sendmail utility in unix AIX. When

mailheader:

```
To: to@gmail.com
From: from@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Subject: Alert
```

status.hmtl -> contains html report spooled using a db query

`(cat ./mailheader ./status.html ) | sendmail -t`

When i try to use the above command from a shell script from a crontab tab  i get below message in log:

cat: 0652-050 Cannot open ./mailheader.
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open ./status.html.

But the shell scripts runs perfectly when i run it manually.

Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: does your `cron` script chdir into the appropriate directory ?

Comment: Apparently i missed this one. This is resolved now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I didnt change directory from crontab and hence i was getting the rror.

used absolute paths and debug to figure out the issue and added `cd` at begining of my script to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths like

```
(cat /there/mailheader /there/status.html ) | sendmail -t
```

Or use `cd`

```
cd /somepath
(cat mailheader status.html ) | sendmail -t
```

But first of all, debug. Add these lines into your script:

```
set -xv
exec >>/tmp/debug.$$ 2>&1
date
pwd
id -a
env
```